# Slideshow background image

Tags: jquery, background, slideshow

I have make a slideshow from background images. You can see this on http://www.mikevierwind.nl/websites/test/

You see the slideshow in the header. Here you see image that rotate. But what is now the problem.

When the slideshow show a new image. The image is going loading. Everytime that the slideshow place a new image. This image must be loaded again. How can i make, that the image loading one time?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to preload the images, see:

[Preloading Images with jQuery and JavaScript](http://engineeredweb.com/blog/09/12/preloading-images-jquery-and-javascript)

Note also that with your code in `load` event, all the images are loaded by the time. Try putting your code in `load` also.